# How to plot a distribution in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a NetLogo model. each turtle has two attributes, "closeness" and "deviation_from_oracle". Now let's say there are 1000 agents in the model. The question is, how can I plot the "closeness" against "deviation_from_oracle" ?

It would also be helpful if I can get a csv file from NetLogo that has the value of closeness and deviaiton_from_oracle of all turtles after for example 1500 steps.

Comment: I'd look into behaviorspace, which makes it pretty easy to save output to a csv, it's in the tools menu, as far as plotting goes, its possible in netlogo, but if you're comfortable with excel, r, or python, probably easier in one of those with a csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely agree with Hugh_Kelley regarding using Behaviorspace to output your values (or custom export functions that might make for easier data cleanup if you're looking to report values for a large dynamic number of turtles- depends on your comfort with your statistical software of choice).

If you do need to plot something on the interface to show your users or something, you may find the `plotxy` function does what you need. For example, you'll need a plot on the interface called "plot 1" and a single blank pen in that plot called "pen-0".

You can control that plot either by manually setting up its x and y extent or by using the `set-plot-...` commands as in this `setup`:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 10
  set-current-plot "plot 1"
  set-current-plot-pen "pen-0"
  set-plot-pen-mode 2
  set-plot-x-range 0 17
  set-plot-y-range 0 25
  reset-ticks
end
```

If you need to have a value plotted for each of your turtles, you can get the turtles to call `plotxy` for whatever values you're looking to plot- here I just use their absolute x coordinate and distance to the center as an example:

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    rt random 61 - 30
    fd 1
    set-plot-pen-color color
    plotxy ( abs xcor ) distance patch 0 0    
  ]
  tick
end
```

This gives output like:

[image]

Where each point was plotted by an individual turtle.

If you want instead some reported mean value, have the observer call `plotxy` instead- another example that plots the average distance to other turtles and the average distance to center:

```
to go
  plotxy mean-closeness-to-others mean-distance-center
  ask turtles [
    rt random 61 - 30
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
end

to-report mean-closeness-to-others
  report mean [ mean map distance sort other turtles ] of turtles
end

to-report mean-distance-center 
  report mean [ distancexy 0 0 ] of turtles
end
```

For an output like:

[image]